# Getting Unexpected token: where error, while trying to output a column value

Tags: java, eclipse

```
try {
    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://E:\\testing.accdb");

    String var="Select Location where Book_Name= '"+textField.getText()+"'";
    PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(var);
    ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()) {
         filename=rs.getString("Location");
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + filename );
}
catch (Exception e ) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Check Your File Details");
}
```

So I am trying to get the value of column location where Book_Name is what the user enters through textField. However I'm getting the error of unepexted token.

Comment: You forgot `FROM ....`

Comment: Insert the table's name in the statement: `Select Location FROM TABLENAME where Book_Name=`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the table name:

"SELECT Location **FROM** BOOK where Book_Name= 'XYZ'"

Comment: Nice, my dear friend. If this comment help you please mark as correct answer.